# Product Category Labelling Automation using Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I've been doing a school project to automate product category labelling. I am using python and need a simplify code using loops and dictionary, but I am new to Python and my code looks very long and inefficient.

So basically I have a product names, and I want to automate the product category labelling. I tried to detect the words in the product names using regex. For example, product named "Daylight Facial Cleanser" which contains "cleanser" will be labelled "Face Wash", and then "Dry Skin Moisturizer Gel" which contains "moisturizer" will be labelled "Moisturizer", etc.

Here's my function :

```
def labelling(text):
    cleanser         = re.findall(re.compile(r'^(?=.*cleanser)+', flags=re.I | re.X), text)
    face_wash        = re.findall(re.compile(r'^(?=.*face)(?=.*wash).+', flags=re.I | re.X), text)
    mask             = re.findall(re.compile(r'^(?=.*mask)+', flags=re.I | re.X), text)
    moisturizer      = re.findall(re.compile(r'^(?=.*moisturizer)+', flags=re.I | re.X), text)

    if cleanser:
        return "Face Wash"
    elif face_wash:
        return "Face Wash"
    elif mask:
        return "Mask"
    elif moisturizer:
        return "Moisturizer"
    else:
        return " "
        
df['category']=df['product_name'].apply(lambda x : labelling(x))
```

can someone explain a simpler function using loops and dictionary so we only input the words and the label in the dictionary, and then call it inside the loops?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and expected output? But you can look at `.str.contains()` for example.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to categorize based on multiple conditions:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product_name':['this is a cleanser here', 'Another phrase is face wash', 'You know, a mask.','We need a  moisturizer', 'No cateogry']})

c_list = [
    df['product_name'].str.contains(r'cleanser', case=False, regex=False),
    df['product_name'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*face)(?=.*wash)', case=False, regex=True),
    df['product_name'].str.contains(r'mask', case=False, regex=False),
    df['product_name'].str.contains(r'moisturizer', case=False, regex=False)
]

categories = ['Face Wash', 'Face Wash', 'Mask', 'Moisturizer']

df['category'] = np.select(c_list, categories, default=' ')
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
                  product_name     category
0      this is a cleanser here    Face Wash
1  Another phrase is face wash    Face Wash
2            You know, a mask.         Mask
3       We need a  moisturizer  Moisturizer
4                  No cateogry
```

I converted three regexps out of four into fixed string check with `regex=False`. If you plan to match whole words only, revert to `regex=True` and use `\b` around the words, like `r'\bcleanser\b'`.

Note the `default=' '` inserts a space in case `np.select` does not match any condition.

You can join the first two  conditions into one:

```py
df['product_name'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*face)(?=.*wash)|cleanser', case=False, regex=True),
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this,

```
# declare Labels
labels = {"cleanser": "Face Wash", "face wash": "Face Wash", "mask": "Mask"}


# re-define the labelling definition to use dict
def labelling(x):
    for k, v in labels.items():
        if k.lower() in x.lower():
            return v

df['category'] = df['product_name'].apply(lambda x: labelling(x))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, it means a lot for me